# Change value from other Java class

Tags: android

In the activity A which contains a mapview and a Java class called map A, and I also add another public class for this activity a called adapter A . So here is a thing , for instance , I want to pass a value of a marker location from map a to adapter A, and adapter A make some change to this value  and return to map A . So im kinda new in Java , can you guys give me some advice that how to pass the value even though it's in different Java class.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: too many "a" s in your question to understand it. Everything is "a": activity, adapter, map, etc.

Comment: not getting your question. Please clear your question and post your code so that we can understand.

Comment: Passing of object in different java class within the flow of same activity is like pass by address as in C language. So as you pass an object and make any changes, all the class will have updated value pointing to the same object reference. Now regarding your issue, it would be good if you post the detail script of your query.